# Error updating Maven repositories' indices in the IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

It is IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2.

Indices of the Maven repositories do not get updated, even if I explicitly go to:

```
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories
```

and click `Update` (literally nothing happens on this click.. not even hanging).

There's a permanent error:

[image]

1. There is no firewall or any other restriction;
2. No, restart, clearing cache, etc. does not help either.

This makes me restart IntelliJ every time I want to change the dependency version or just change anything that has relation with remote/local repositories. E.g. when I change the version, it is not resolved immediately, but after I restart IDE, it gets resolved (however, then I can't get back to the previous version.. I need another restart, again..).

Any ideas?

Comment: What message is shown when you hover over the error in this dialog? The full error is also printed in idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action).

Comment: @Andrey "Project already disposed" for remote, and nothing for local.

Comment: Please submit an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with IDE logs attached (use Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data action) after IDE restart, pressing the **Update** button for both repositories.

Comment: You have to select the repositories you want to update, click update (even multiple repos) and then click OK - then it's updating but atm the bug still persists. It's annoying as hell.